# How would I go about creating a file compressor similar to ZIP archives in a language like C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, file, compression

So I was thinking of how a .zip archive is structured and then I thought, how could I create my own archive format.

Comment: Read a book about compression algorithms.  Does anybody have a solid recommendation?

Comment: By writing the appropriate code. The scope of this question is rather broad--perhaps you should try it out, and see where you actually have trouble? (Voting to close because it's inappropriately broad.)

Comment: If you're thinking about archive formats and compression algorithms, the choice of language isn't really relevant, and your question's too broad anyway. (If you're asking how to implement something to compress/decompress a given format, then this is *way* too broad.)

Comment: Do you know of any articles about the .zip structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to know what you want to compress. E.G. zip works great for many things, but not so well for audio files. FLAC works well for audio, but poorly on text files ( provided you could find a way to apply it )

Once you had a compression scheme you would allocate the appropriate metadata so you could later decompress the information, followed by the compressed data.

Perhaps you would research [A lossless compression method such as Entropy Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_encoding). You might decided that Arithmetic coding was more optimal than Huffman coding and decide to implement an Arithmetic codec. You might also look at Dictionary encoding if you are more interested in compressing text.

#### Edit in response to comment

One would have to include the entropy tables decided upon when encoding the data so it could be later decoded.

Take for example JPEG. JPEG uses a Colorspace transformation to YCrCb, Quantization, A Discrete Cosine Transformation, and then uses Huffman coding on the data. The color space transformation metadata is included in the headers. (how many bits per color and how many samples per channel, along with the size of the image. ) The quantization tables are included and an index of which table match which channel. And the used huffman tables to encode the DC and AC Coefficients. The Discrete Cosine Transformation and ZigZag Coefficient pattern is part of the standard. So after De-quantization you must IDCT the information and dezigzag the coefficients.

1. Basically for JPEG.

   - Read the given tables in the header.
   - Figure out the entropy encoded format with the header info about
     size and color.
   - Use the Huffman table to expand the data segment
   - Dequantize appropriately
   - IDCT and de zigzag

You would have to make your own standard, figure out the minimum information needed to recover the information and store it in a way readable without knowing details of whats inside.

I don't know about .zip, but I would imagine it would have a couple dictionary tables and a couple entropy tables. You would de-entropy encode the datasegment (which must be somehow determined by standard or marker ), then use a reverse dictionary substitution.

Comment: How would I structure this metadata. e.g. Compressed file structure then...

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to know thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download the sources of [bzip2](http://bzip.org/downloads.html) and compile them. And then go from there.